# template specialization of unique_ptr generating member function

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, polymorphism

I am trying to make comm class with template variable.
My colleague ask me to use std::unique_ptr for memory management.
But I think I failed to implement polymorphysm.

I wrote code as the following.

```
template<typename env>
class Comm{
public:
    Comm(size_t rank, size_t world_size): rank(rank), world_size(world_size) {};
    Comm(){};
    ~Comm(){};
    int rank;
    int world_size;
}
template<typename env>
std::unique_ptr<Comm<env> > createComm(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << "empty comm" << std::endl;
    return std::make_unique< Comm<env> >();
};
template<>
std::unique_ptr<Comm<MKL> > createComm(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << "SERIALcomm" << std::endl;
    return std::make_unique< Comm<MKL> >( 0, 1 );
}
template<>
std::unique_ptr<Comm<MPI> > createComm(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << "MPIcomm" << std::endl;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int myRank ,nRanks;
    MPI_Comm_rank(mpi_comm, &myRank);
    MPI_Comm_size(mpi_comm, &nRanks);
    assert(nRanks>0);
    assert(myRank>=0);
    return std::make_unique< Comm<MPI> >( (size_t) myRank, (size_t) nRanks );
}
```

And here is a test code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    auto comm = createComm<MKL>(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

and I've got
"empty comm"
as a output.

What should I do to make MKL type or MPI comm object using createComm method?

Comment: Off topic, but `~Comm(){};` is an active pessimization because now your type is not trivially destructible. Write `~Comm() = default;` or don't declare the destructor at all.

Comment: To your problem: Use `template<> std::unique_ptr<Comm<MKL>> createComm<MKL>(...) { ... }` to specialize the function.

Comment: Please make a complete, minimal example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>. As it stands, your code looks like it should work, and I can get it to work here: https://godbolt.org/z/963E6hhPn so the problem is in something you've not shown us.

Comment: Why `template<typename env>` though? If you had no use of it when making the class generic?

Comment: The program [works/compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/963E6hhPn) without any error. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It is super hard to make minimal working example, this is the second time which I failed. Whatsoever, as @user12002570 and

Comment: @Artyer ask me, I recompiled and put **relevant headers carefully**, and it works as i expected.

Comment: also, I thought that I must make destruct for every class. @chrysante showed me it is not need, or I need to make better destructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You got the syntax wrong:

```
template<>
std::unique_ptr<Comm<MKL> > createComm(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << "SERIALcomm" << std::endl;
    return std::make_unique< Comm<MKL> >( 0, 1 );
}
```

should be

```
template<>
std::unique_ptr<Comm<MKL> > createComm<MKL>(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << "SERIALcomm" << std::endl;
    return std::make_unique< Comm<MKL> >( 0, 1 );
}
```

Here is a complete and minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void f()
{ std::cout << "f<T>()\n"; }

template<>
void f<int>()
{ std::cout << "f<int>()\n"; }


int main()
{
    f<int>(); // prints f<int>()
}
```

[demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d95fd78df85e148)

Learn more about those features (don't guess C++ syntax, this will bite HARD):
[CPP Reference, *Explicit specializations of function templates*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization#Explicit_specializations_of_function_templates).

Comment: `createComm` and `createComm<MKL>` (and also `createComm<>`) would be equivalent in those specializations since `env = MKL` is be deduced from the return type

Comment: You have to actually use the parameter, like in the original example `std::unique_ptr<Comm<env>>` allows `env=MKL` to be deduced when the return type is given as `std::unique_ptr<Comm<MKL>>`. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bfdab1be62e36b5

Comment: Ho yes, my bad.